# android stacking an object above layouts like the keyboard application

Tags: android, layout

how to get an object such as a button and stack it above any layout in any application, just like the android keyboard application does?
not asking about how to write a service class but asking for the java or xml syntax for doing this stacking.

Answer (score 0):

The xml for a keyboard is the same as for an activity.  THe behavior for this is handled by the OS putting us in a separate Window, not by any xml magic.